# When running Firebase IOS app the screen is blank after load

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift5

I made an IOS App (firebase) swift 5.0 Xcode 12 (latest) app and I have had no issues with it until now. When running I am greeted with the load and after loading it's just black with the white outline for the nav at the bottom. I have no idea of the cause and any help is appreciated. Here is everything it says in console when running. w/ timestamps

```
2021-03-29 10:33:40.238472-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186902] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
DEBUG: SUCCESSFULLY REGISTERED FOR NOTIFICATIONS
2021-03-29 10:33:41.282635-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186878] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM012002] Error in application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: remote notifications are not supported in the simulator
DEBUG: Registered with FCM Token:  d-tODtnQjUvgqn6f0UcNdj:APA91bEj4jb0W0bPvtw_nUbgksQFli6hc12alhyOOWM7LrdFV3v4-JEYNEnj5bO6sAHYlh_eDJAD1wIWy9aapAit-I63cCcqZnUg8iFzdZfPb5XF7A0YoLIT1akLAyxDgt6hgjiLglts
2021-03-29 10:33:41.379526-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186878] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60803000 started
2021-03-29 10:33:41.395343-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186878] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see STACK_OVERFLOW_BLOCKED_THIS_GOOGLE_URL)
2021-03-29 10:33:41.694578-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186878] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2021-03-29 10:33:41.724263-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186900] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2021-03-29 10:33:41.724790-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186900] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023220] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2021-03-29 10:33:42.016835-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:186887] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at users/IJagnbOSExgMgAZwtPqyXU0ri9F3 failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.
2021-03-29 10:34:09.795076-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:187300] [] nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed
2021-03-29 10:35:12.024585-0700 SocialSappApp[13689:188089] 6.33.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (600003e31d18) Stream error: 'Cancelled: Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out waiting for new targets.'
```

I have been attempting to fix for 2 days and this is my last resort. I can provide any extra info if need be.

Thank you in advance,
Zach.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good troubleshooting start with searching SO to see if someone has asked a similar question. I searched for *remote notifications are not supported in the simulator* and found a [number of matches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5Dremote+notifications+are+not+supported+in+the+simulator). Do any of those help?

Comment: If not, when asking questions it's important to include the CODE you're using and then tell is what kind of troubleshooting you've done. For example, add a breakpoint in the code that happens after the `load` and then step through it, line by line. At that time you can examine your variables and the code flow until something isn't right. That's what we need to see in your question in order to help. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).